# django queryset .first() not rendering on html

Tags: django, django-queryset, render

I am only learning django so any guide would be much appreciated.
I am creating an app where authenticated users can like other posts. On one of the pages, I would like to render and show the post with most likes.
Please see my code below:

models.py:

```
class Enter(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=200, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    competitor = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_enter')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', null=False, blank=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_likes', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Enter, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

views.py:

```
class CurrentOrderList(generic.ListView):

    model = Enter
    queryset = Enter.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('likes')[0]
    template_name = 'competition.html'
```

competition.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    {% for entry in enter_list %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div>
                        <img class="card-img-top" src=" {{ entry.featured_image.url }}">
                        <div>
                            <p class="competitor text-muted">By: {{ entry.competitor }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{ entry.title }}</h2>
                    <hr />
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ entry.created_on}} <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
                        {{ entry.number_of_likes }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

If I remove `[0]` (or `.first()`) from the views.py list does get rendered on the page, but some of the items get duplicated - ** using `.distinct()` does not remove duplicates**

How can I display the entry with highest amount of likes? Thank you!

Comment: Using `[0]` makes no sense, since this is a `ListView`, and then you return a single element, not a queryset.

Comment: It also makes the item not iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to order by the *number* of likes, that is something else than order by likes. By doing `.order_by('-likes')`, you order in descending order by the primary key of the *liker*, and thus the same `Enter` appears as much as there are likers.

If you want to order by the number of likes, you work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count


class CurrentOrderList(generic.ListView):
    model = Enter
    queryset = (
        Enter.objects.filter(status=1)
        .alias(nlikes=Count('likes'))
        .order_by('-nlikes')
    )
    template_name = 'competition.html'
```

Using `[0]` or `.first()` however makes *no* sense, then these are not querysets, but `Enter` objects. The `queryset` should have a value of type `QuerySet`, not a model object.

If you only want to show the most liked post, this is a `DetailView`, and you thus use `get_object` instead:

```
from django.db.models import Count


class CurrentOrderList(generic.DetailView):
    model = Enter
    queryset = (
        Enter.objects.filter(status=1)
        .alias(nlikes=Count('likes'))
        .order_by('-nlikes')
    )
    template_name = 'competition.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_queryset().first()
```

then it passes that object as `object` to the template, so you don't use a `{% for … %}` to enumerate, you only need to render `object`.

Comment: Using the code you provided I get the following error - django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'nlikes' into field. Choices are: comments, competitor, competitor_id, content, created_on, featured_image, id, likes, slug, status, title, updated_on

Comment: @DarkoZlatarek: you used the `alias(nlikes=...)`?

Comment: @DarkoZlatarek: what Django version did you use?

Comment: I am using 3.2.19

Comment: I copied your code and replaced mine with it.

Comment: @DarkoZlatarek: I made a typo: it is `likes`, not `linkes`. might have been autocorrect.

Comment: Oh yes.. works brilliantly now.. How do I show only most liked post from this? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Interesting.. The code does work and I think I am grasping what you are explaining to me. It is very much appreciated. Thank you